# Can not link email

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

Why is the email address not highlighted as a link?

git@vger.kernel.org

I try to format it like:

```
[git@vger.kernel.org](mailto:git@vger.kernel.org)
```

Comment: It's `mailto:`, no underscore. Links are however, very restricted, and `mailto` is not on the whitelist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , Why did you edit question in right format? I think it should be remain in wrong way to other users understand what is the problem , it takes minuets from me.

Comment: @Arman: I fixed a spelling mistake, I didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is it _spelling mistake_ ? I thought that was problem maker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `mailto:` urls are not supported, and they probably won't be. From [Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54774/is-mailto-supported):

> ### Is mailto supported?
>
> `mailto` is not supported in posts. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/including-sos-url-creates-a-link-that-isnt-closed/29523#29523) for the official establishment of this.

and following the link

> we've never really supported that (email, feh, I spit on email).